# Creating a text file via SSH shell

Tags: linux, git, bash

I am trying to create a BASH shell script that runs through SSH on my shared hosting account to automate the git website control system detailed in:

```
http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website.
```

So far my bash script is right out of the above article:

```
cd ~/mydomains; mkdir $name.git;
cd ~/mydomains/$name.git; git init --bare; 
/bin/vi ~/domains/$name.git/hooks/post-update
```

The first 2 lines work as expected.

when I add the third line the script seems to freeze up. the path to vi is /bin/vi in my environment.

Directly from the article I want the to perform the following:

```
vi /path/website.git/hooks/post-update
```

then insert:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/htdocs git checkout -f
```

Then close the file.

Could anyone offer me some advice on what to do now?

Comment: Why do you want to use `vi`? Does `echo 'GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/htdocs git checkout -f' >> /path/website.git/hooks/post-update` not suffice?

Comment: Thanks for looking, I'm not experienced with Bash so just following article step by step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you try to use vi in script just to add line into file?
Problem is that vi is interactive, but you're looking how to automate this ;-)

You should use

```
echo "GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/htdocs git checkout -f" >> ~/domains/$name.git/hooks/post-update
```

Comment: -1, this is not an answer to his question, and there is no reason not to use vim.

Comment: What this minus is for? His problem isn't with hook, but with script, which makes this hook!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I can't undo my vote, but I will if you make a minor edit to your post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to make the hook script executable before git will use it.

```
chmod +x /path/website.git/hooks/post-update
```

After that, after pushing, the script ought to be executed.

Comment: will do, I believe thats the next line in the article, Regards, Bill